# How do populate a DataGrid based on a Selection from a Combo Box?

Tags: datagrid, combobox, dataset

I have used the Dataset wizard to create a dataset that I have used as a data source for a data grid in a Windows Form application using VB.NET.  In addition I have a combo box that has a data source from another dataset created by the wizard.  Now I want to filter the data grid based on the selection from the combo box.  How can this be done since I have used the wizard for the dataset creations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the [RowFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property?

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    ds.Tables(0).DefaultView.RowFilter = "MyProperty = '" + combo.Text + "'"
End Sub
```